# Add RSS Viewer to Tabbed Application XCode

Tags: ios, uitableview, rss-reader

I have a tabbed app and I'd like to set one of the tabs (UITableViewController) to display content from RSS feed.
How do I do that? Is there any tutorial or very easy open source code about it? I'm a beginner, don't understand the pro tuts I've been reading for days.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the sample codes

[iphone-rss-reader-application-with-source-code](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-rss-reader-application-with-source-code.php)

[how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial)

[Iphone RSS fun small program](http://www.sourcecodeprojects.com/1093770/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the first one you suggested. I've already seen the second and third, and they are too complicated for me. I was looking for an RSS Viewer with a UIWebView, but that would be fine, if I will make it work :)